# ArgumentOutOfRangeException running HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html-agility-pack

I'm at my wits end.  I keep getting this exception with HtmlAgilityPack whenever I attempt to select nodes using XPath.  The problem remains even if I start a brand new solution with just this example (so it's not a problem with my application code interfering somehow.  There's nothing wrong with the webpage, or my internet connection or anything like that.  I know I've had this working before.  I even suspected a corrupted dll somehow and re-downloaded it, but to no avail.  Any ideas??

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var web = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = web.Load("http://www.google.com");
            var root = doc.DocumentNode;

            var links = root.SelectNodes("//a");
            // Error!  ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. 
            // Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
        }
    }
}

/*
    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
    Parameter name: index
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
       at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeNavigator.MoveToFirstChild()
       at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathDescendantIterator.MoveNext()
       at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.DescendantQuery.Advance()
       at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathSelectionIterator.MoveNext()
       at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.SelectNodes(String xpath)
       at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) 

*/
```

edit:

Well...I'm not sure how it happened or what it did, but I found the .dll installed in a GAC_MSIL folder.  Removing that immediately resolved the issue.  So, nevermind!

Comment: Works just fine for me. Are you maybe behind a proxy server which is causing issues? If you print `doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml`, what does it read?

Comment: No proxy or anything, possibly just a corrupted dll.  See my edits.

Comment: Funky :) never had that happen. Please proceed to post your solution as an anser and mark it accepted to close the question.